# Monitor and create logs of W3WP.exe process CPU utilization and request URL's when CPU spikes more than 50%

Tags: visual-studio, iis, w3wp

In our Application there are more the 2000 pages which are deployed in prod server.  Sometime when user browse some URL's the CPU spikes going more than 70%. I can not find when it's occurs and which URL create this. So can any one tell me best open source tool to Monitor and Create logs of W3WP.exe process CPU utilization and request URL's when CPU spikes more than 50%.

Comment: Spikes just don't mean that much.  Could be the jitter compiling code, could be a gen #2 garbage collection, could be the OS handling a lot of page faults.  You'll need to get ahead by running a load test, if CPU usage is now consistently high then and only then do you have a good reason to use a profiler to find the bottlenecks.

Answer (score 3):

### procdump + windbg

There is a sysinternals tool called [procdump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) which can automatically create a memory dump of your process for analysis when cpu exceeds a threshold.

From the command line usage:

```
-c  CPU threshold at which to create a dump of the process.
```

Once you have a process dump you will need to load it into [windbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx) in order to analyze what's taking up all the cpu cycles. Covering off windbg is pretty big, but here's briefly what you need to do:

- load the SOS dll (managed debug extension)
- call the `!runaway` command to get list of long running threads
- dive into a long running thread by selecting it and calling `!clrstack` command

There are many blogs on using windbg. Here is [one](http://improve.dk/how-to-identify-which-request-caused-a-runaway-thread-using-windbg/)  example. A great resource on analyzing these types of issues is Tess Ferrandez's [blog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-US?rq=site%3Ablogs.msdn.microsoft.com%2Ftess&rn=tess&query=high%20cpu).

### perfmon + procdump + windbg

Perfmon can help you see if the issue is related to high rates of memory allocation which is causing garbage collection. You can look at CPU for w3wp as well as allocation rates for the process and the number of Gen 2 collections occurring. Gen 2 collections mean Gen 1 and 0 are also collected, meaning it can be an expensive operation. Counters to look at:

- `# Gen 2 Collections`
- `% Time in GC`
- `Allocated Bytes/second`

If you see some very high allocation rates, you will still need a memory dump (procdump) and windbg to analyse what the root cause is.
Again - Tess Ferrandez has a [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2006/06/22/asp-net-case-study-high-cpu-in-gc-large-objects-and-high-allocation-rates/) post on this flavor of high cpu. In this post the issue is allocating large objects onto the heap.

### perfmon + appcmd

I haven't tried this myself but in theory it should work, and is simpler than other options - though will not produce same level of detail. You can configure [perfmon alerts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722414(v=ws.11).aspx) on cpu for w3wp.exe. The alerts can be configured to run a task. You can create a batch file which runs the [appcmd](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=appcmd.exe) IIS tool and tell it to dump all the running requests:

```
appcmd list requests > c:\temp\high-cpu-requests.txt
```

This way you will get a list of long running requests when the cpu is high, and hopefully be able to work out offending page from there.

Answer (score 0):

[IIS Advanced Logging](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging) may help you here.

Whilst it will not give you CPU Utilisation per request, it can log CPU utilisation in general. What you could do is try and match these spikes to the requests that come before it.